Вычислить направление скрола на смартфоне
Вот JS
$(document).ready(function() {
var last_scroll = 0;
window.onscroll = function(){
  if(window.scrollY > last_scroll){
    $(".wrapper").addClass("bottom");
  }else{
    $(".wrapper").removeClass("bottom");
  }
  last_scroll = window.scrollY;
}
});

Это нужно для добавления класса bottom в обертку wrapper. Я так скрываю элементы некоторые при скроле вниз. Вот ссылка  Пример анимации при скроле
На эмуляторе работает. На старом телефоне тоже. Но заказчик пишет и шлет видео.
зависит от чувствительности тач сенсора
пользователь делает микродвижение в обратную сторону, конда останавливает скрол, вы должны его игнорировать
аналогично система делает обратный скрол в верхнем и нижнем положении фрейма, это тоже нужно игнорировать

как не работает
Какой скрипт можно применить для вычисления направления скрола?

Попробуй вычитать window.scrollY из last_scroll, в зависимости от того положительное число получается или отрицательное можно понять направление скролла.
Также можешь посмотреть варианты тут: Как отследить направление скролла на станице? JS
